# DataGridView change cells background and restore default style

Tags: c#, datagridview, styles

In my DGV, after clicking on a cell, I want to change the background color of all the cells of the same column with some value. After clicking on another cell, the previous cell (and all its column) must restore default style

```
        int    currCell = dgvLogHeader.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        string pattern = dgvLogHeader.CurrentCell.Value.ToString();
        dgvLogHeader.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.ScrollBar;
        dgvLogHeader.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Info;

        for (int j=0; j < dgvLogHeader.Rows.Count; j++ ) {
            //dgvLogHeader.Columns[currCell].
            if (dgvLogHeader.Rows[j].Cells[currCell].Value.ToString() == pattern) {
                dgvLogHeader.Rows[j].Cells[currCell].Style.BackColor = Color.Brown;
            }
        }
```

But after that cells have changed background and the default style is lost.

Comment: Make sure to __reset__ cells that no longer should be marked. To do so set the color to Color.Empty!

Comment: Have I  to remember all the cells that have been repainted? why doesn't work 
dgvLogHeader.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.ScrollBar;
        dgvLogHeader.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = SystemColors.Info;

Comment: It doesn't override the color of __individually__ set cells. These will always show their individual color until you reset it to Color.Empty.

Comment: Is there a quick way to do a color reset and paint new cells? Not through cycles, in a cycle it's slow, it seems to me

Comment: See my answer: Ideally it uses only two calls, one to reset the last column and one to color the current one..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way to do it:

```
private void dgvLogHeader_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgvLogHeader.Columns)
    {
        if (col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor != Color.Empty)
            col.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Empty;
    }
    dgvLogHeader.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
}
```

This first resets each column with a color to default (`Color.Empty`) and then colors the current column.

Note that this will not reset any colors you have set in **individual cells**!

The reset those you need to set each to  `Color.Empty`.

You may want to add a

```
dgvLogHeader.ClearSelection();
```

to clear the selection of the clicked cell.

**But**: If you need to decide on the colors on an individual basis, depending on Cell values then you will have to cycle over the Cells. This is best done in the `CellPainting` event as this is called in an optimized way to  include only the shown cells. Note that it is called on a per cell basis, so you need to honor the `e.ColumnIndex` and `e.RowIndex` values..

**Update:** Now that you have clarfied to question, indeed you need to loop over either all or all visible cells..

Here is a function you could call to do so:

```
private void markCells(DataGridView dgv, string pattern)
{
    dgv.SuspendLayout();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
            cell.Style.BackColor = cell.Value.ToString() == pattern ?
                Color.LightBlue : Color.Empty;
    dgv.ResumeLayout();
    //dgv.ClearSelection()
}
```

If quickly goes over the whole DGV; you could call it e.g. from a `Textbox.TextChange` event.

It suspends layout while setting the colors, so it should be fast and without flicker..

If you only want to search in one column you can add an extra condition, maybe like this:

```
cell.Style.BackColor = cell.Value.ToString() == pattern &&  
                       cell.ColumnIndex == dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex?
```

and also put it in a `CellClick` event

Comment: Yes indeed there was a typo, I want to paint the cells of the column with the same value(not all cells of column), and after selecting a cell in another column, paint the cells in a new one, and in the previous column, return the default style.

Comment: I updated the answer with genaral code that avoids a variable to keep track of the last marked column.