# How can i change the buttons color in the data grid view?

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, colors

(i am sorry for english mistakes)
Hello,
i am trying to change the color from the buttons inside a datagridview. I have fed the dgv with data from a sql Server, which is working perfectly fine. I get all the data i need. Then i added buttons on Index[0] for each row in the grid, to open a 2nd window for editing purpose (works fine too). But i also want the buttons to change individually the color. I have a column Index[5] which is called "Status", there are 3 different kinds possible: "active" "expire" and "expired". The "if cell = 'active'" works and spots if its true. But what doesn't work is the color changing code.

I already tried quiet a few things and wasted a whole day with it.
I tried "row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;" and ForeColor, changed Color.Green to System.Drawing.Color.Green. Tried to refresh it each time it changes something and then just once if its finished. I shortened the code to only active and tried testdata with only actives, which doesn't work either. I tried to use the debugger, but couldn't find anything with my little knowledge. I tried "dgvAlleAnträge.Rows[row.Index].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;" and changed the buttons to every kind of "Flat"-Style because someone said this would work.

```
    `private void AlleAntraege_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string con = "Data Source=" + Properties.Settings.Default.Server_Name + "; Initial Catalog=" + Properties.Settings.Default.Name_Of_DB + ";Integrated Security=" + Properties.Settings.Default.Integrated_Security;
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(con);
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
            string sqlquery = Properties.Settings.Default.sqlquery;
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 50" + sqlquery, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sdr = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sdr.Fill(dt);
            dgvAlleAnträge.DataSource = dt;
            sqlconn.Close();

            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[2].HeaderCell.Value = "Antrags ID";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Value = "In-Pro-Nr.";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[6].HeaderCell.Value = "Erstellungsdatum";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[7].HeaderCell.Value = "Antragsteller UserID";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[9].HeaderCell.Value = "IOW";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[10].HeaderCell.Value = "Datum Von";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[11].HeaderCell.Value = "Datum Bis";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[12].HeaderCell.Value = "Status Mail";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[13].HeaderCell.Value = "Beschreibung";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[14].HeaderCell.Value = "Stellvertreter UserID";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[15].HeaderCell.Value = "Anwender UserID";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[16].HeaderCell.Value = "Anwender Vorname";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[17].HeaderCell.Value = "Anwender Nachname";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[18].HeaderCell.Value = "Anwender Email";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[19].HeaderCell.Value = "Anwender Firma";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[22].HeaderCell.Value = "Von System Name";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[23].HeaderCell.Value = "Von System IP";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[25].HeaderCell.Value = "Nach System Name";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[26].HeaderCell.Value = "Nach System IP";
            dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[5].Visible = true;
            (dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[0] as DataGridViewButtonColumn).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvAlleAnträge.Rows)
            {
                if (row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().Contains("aktiv") || row.Cells[5].Value.ToString().Contains("Aktiv"))
                {
                    (dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[0] as DataGridViewButtonColumn).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                    row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

`

I want the buttons to change the backcolor to green if the cell in column "Status" = "active"

Comment: @TaW it looks like he is changing the color of some button outside called "button1" not any button inside the dgv

Comment: _changed the buttons to every kind of "Flat"-Style_ It will work indeed; where is the code you use? Example: `(dgvAlleAnträge.Columns[0] as DataGridViewButtonColumn).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;`

Comment: No, he isn't but my link did..My bad..

Comment: @TaW i tried it and it changed to flat (with the designer once and now with this code) but it didn't change the color inside the dgv

Comment: It does here and everywhere else. Show the code and make sure not to leave old code hanging around.. Also Do use the debugger to make sure you hit the right lines!! Also get your spelling right: at one place you test for 'aktiv' and in the post you write about 'active..

Comment: Thats because i am from germany and in Germany its called "aktiv" with a k. And i changed the code here, so you can see the whole code. And i even tried to color the whole dgv just to see if its working @TaW

Comment: Ja, gut, nur muss es im code halt einheitlich sein. Und? Die eigentliche Frage war ja ob der Code in die `if` Klausel geht?? Was sagt der Debugger? (Ich würde den Flatstyle auch lieber im Designer für alle Zeilen setzen und nicht mehr verändern; es sollen ja auch alle gleich gestylt sein..) - Und wenn ich schon Vorschläge mache: Es sollt nie nötig sein auf 'Aktiv' __und__ 'aktiv' zu testen. Zum Vergleich nimmt man eine Konstante (die man auch leicht ändern kann) und Eingaben müssen entweder durch auswahllisten beschränkt oder bei Erfassug geprüft und korrigiert werden...

Comment: Der debugger sagt mir, dass er in die if reingeht und den Hintergrund tatsächlich auch Grün macht. Jedoch kann ich das in dem Programm selbst nicht sehen. Die Indexe sind ebenfalls korrekt, da das mit dem ändern vom Flatstyle auch funktioniert. row.Cells[0].Style.BackColor mit der Value {Name=Green, ARGB=(255, 0, 128, 0)} sagt der mir bezüglich farbe.

Comment: und bezüglich aktiv und Aktiv, das will meine Abteilung so haben... leider. Funktioniert aber.

Comment: Na das klingt ja schräg. Er macht es grün und man sieht es nicht?? Was meldet der debugger, wenn du __danach__ die Zellen untersuchst? (Sprich : Teste ob eine andere Stelle auch herumfärbt..)

Comment: Also nachdem er eine Stelle gefärbt hat, springt er wieder in das foreach, dann ins if und dann färbt er die nächste Zelle Grün.

Comment: Jaja, aber gibt es sonstwo im code noch stellen, die die BackColor ändern?

Comment: Nein, das ist die einzige aktive stelle, die was verändert. Der Rest ist nur auf "Knopfdruck".

Comment: Seltsam. Ich schlage vor, du machst dir ein kleine testfenster in dem du das button färben mal neu testest, damit du weißt wie es sicher geht und du im großen code mit mehr sicherheit weitermachen kannst.. Hier mein test setup:

Comment: `(dataGridView3.Columns[2] as DataGridViewButtonColumn).FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
  (dataGridView3.Columns[2] as DataGridViewButtonColumn).DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Fuchsia;

    dataGridView3.RowCount = 9;
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView3.RowCount; i++)
        {
      dataGridView3[0, i].Value = i;
        dataGridView3[1, i].Value = "-" + i + "-";
         dataGridView3[2, i].Style.BackColor = i % 3 == 1 ? Color.Red : Color.Wheat;
      dataGridView3[2, i].Style.ForeColor = i % 3 == 1 ? Color.Orange : Color.Silver;
  }`

Comment: Danke dir, ohne dein Sample wäre ich nicht auf die Lösung gekommen.

Comment: Nein, eigentlich ist der cast nur nötig um den FlatStyle zu setzen, der in einer Textspalte nicht existiert. Die BackColor kann man ganz normal ohne cast setzen.. Mein Beispiel tut das ja auch. Ich habe einen link angefügt, der die konflikte zwischen Style und DefaultCellStyle erklärt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`row.Cell[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;` doesn't work. You have to use `(DataGridView1.Columns[row.Index] as (DataGridViewButtonColumn).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;` Then your Buttons will get the color you want.

Comment: This doesn't quite cover the situation. For are better discussion of the issue [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529612/datagridview-change-cells-background-and-restore-default-style/50562405#50562405) -

Comment: But somehow it doesen't do it here in my program.